# Binding combobox to two datatables

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to populate combobox by binding it to one datatable and bind its selected value to another datatable?

```
<ComboBox                   
  Name="cbo"
  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
  SelectedValuePath="ID"
/>
cbo.ItemsSource = datatable1.defaultview
```

I want the selected item to be set based on a value in another datatable

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do that, what you can do is create a custom class with both the data table and bind the values to the combo box.

Then you can set DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath different.